# How to transform only face with geometry node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I know it's possible to do this sort of effect using "explode" particle system,but it's not very controllable.

I would like to know if it would be possible in geometry node to either split-edges and move only faces from a noise (without keeping every vertex connected) to act like a particle system, or to instance on face the original face to work with instance paradigm?

Comment: My only "solution" currently is to separate by lose part after splitted the edge, but it is verry slow to work with 500k objects.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

[image]

Monkey on left, 500k vert monkey on right.

I'm splitting the edges, then capturing the position of every *face* and then using that as a lookup on a noise texture, to displace every vertex.  Since at this point, every vertex is a part of only a single face, the face data gets cast identically to each vertex of a face, and since the inputs of the noise texture are all the same for each vertex of a face, and the normals of the vertices are all just the face normals at this point, all vertices move in the same way-- the faces stay the same size and shape as they originally were, no distortion.

Adjusting the GN *is* a little laggy on the 500k vert version, but I've certainly dealt with worse, and we should expect operations on that many verts to get laggy.  Once we do the edge split, we're no longer dealing with 500k verts but 2 million.  And we need to edge split in order to, you know, split the edges.

Comment: It is somewhat what I needed, but seem to lack modularity to move faces like it is possible to do with instances. (here it moves only among normal + noise + rotation is hard)

Comment: How do you want it to move?  For rotation, probably your issue is that you're rotating about object center, but wish to rotate about face center?  Translate each face by its negative position, rotate, translate by its original, positive position to rotate about a different center.  But really, this should be specified in the question-- possibly, in more than one question.